# Scala: I have a Set[X] and function (X) => Future[Y] and want to output a Future[Map[X, Y]]

Tags: scala, future, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I have:

- input set: `Set[X]` and
- function: `(X) => Future[Y]`

Running the function on the set, I'd like to output a:

- `Future[Map[X, Y]]`

I'm having a slow Scala brain day. Please help me come up with a transformation for the above. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key piece is [`Future.traverse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future%24). As a first step you could write the following:

```
def toSet[A, B](keys: Set[A], computeValue: A => Future[B]) =
  Future.traverse(keys)(computeValue)
```

But this returns a `Future[Set[B]]`, which isn't exactly what you want. So you add in the keys and convert to a map at the end:

```
def toMap[A, B](keys: Set[A], computeValue: A => Future[B]): Future[Map[A, B]] =
  Future.traverse(keys)(k => computeValue(k).map(k -> _)).map(_.toMap)
```

And you're done.

Comment: brilliant, thanks for helping so quickly and thoroughly!